# Laravel BelongsTo Through relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, route-model-binding

How to implement BelongsToThrough Relationship in Laravel?

I have Table:

```
**projects_table**
id 

**categories_table**
id
project_id 

**properties_table**
id
category_id
```

> Category BelongsTo Project

```
public function project(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

> Property BelongsTo Category

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

**How can we make a relationship?**

> Property BelongsTo Project Through Category

```
public function project(){
     return $this->belongsToThrough('App\Project', 'App\Category');
}
```

***EDIT QUESTION.***

Because I want to do multi-tenancy on my application, and the tenancy is PORJECT. I want to separate Category and Property by Project.

CATEGORY is belongsTo PROJECT
PROPERTY is belongsTo CATEGORY

so I want to make relationship between PROPERTY and PROJECT via CATEGORY.
for now, I need to add: `project_id` on both **categories** and **properties** tables and I think that this is not the right way.

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh, belongsToThrough is not the relationship type of Laravel. I tried to follow Prafulla's answer with hasOneThrough relationship, but this is not working.

Comment: Check out this package which adds the `belongsToThrough` relationship https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `hasOneThrough` with all keys specified like so

```
public function project()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            Project::class,
            Category::class,
            'id', # foreign key on intermediary -- categories
            'id', # foreign key on target -- projects
            'category_id', # local key on this -- properties
            'project_id' # local key on intermediary -- categories
        );
    }
```

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do `$project->category->property` as you have a one-to-one relationship between Project and Category and again a one-to-one relationship between Category and property, beside this, if you want to define a relationship between Project and Property through you may consider [has-one-through](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) relaationship.

In Project model

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Property', 'App\Category');
}
```

and in Property model

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Project', 'App\Category');
}
```

May be

In that case, you can also do something like

in Property model

```
public function project()
{    
   return $this->category->project( or projects);

   // or if Category and properties have many-to-many relationship you can do 
   return $this->categories->with('projects')->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case, I cannot use hasOneThrough relationship.

this is the error. 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.property_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `properties` where exists (select * from `projects` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `projects`.`category_id` where `categories`.`deleted_at` is null and `properties`.`id` = `categories`.`property_id` and `id` = 1 and `categories`.`deleted_at` is null and `projects`.`deleted_at` is null) and `properties`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: Can you tell me, how Property and Category models are related?

Comment: `class Property extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
    }
}`

Comment: so I want to have Property Model to has a belongsTo Project Model via Category Model

Comment: @LimSocheat I am asking about foreign key only, let me know the foreign  key that relates these two tables

Comment: please take a look this package, I want something like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through#usage
`HasManyThrough`
Project → has many → Category → has many → Property

`BelongsToThrough`
Property → belongs to → Category → belongs to → Project

Comment: Get this error. 

`message: "Trying to get property 'project' of non-object"`

Comment: all are belongsTo relationships.  `Property` → belongsTo → `Category` → belongsTo → `Project`

Comment: then you are able to get `$property->cateory`, `$category->project`, `$category->property` and `$project->category` am I correct?

Comment: $categories->properties (hasMany), $project->categories (hasMany)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199459/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-lim-socheat).

Answer (score 0):

Your property `belongsTo` is incorrect. Property belongs to Category.

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id');
}
```

Now you can get project from property like below:

```
{{ $property->category->project->project_attribute }}
```

Comment: Hi Zahid, I have updated my question! I want to build a multi-tenancy application. so I need to filter CATEGORY and PROPERTY by PROJECT.

Comment: you are getting what you want like this. what is the problem using like this?? what exactly you are trying to do??

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it like this. If you want to access project Using properties. Then check this following steps which I mention as per your requirement.

**Category.php Model**

```
public function project(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','project_id','id');
}
```

**Property.php model** here you're doing wrong. You can access it directly you've to made relationship with categories first and from categories will get project.

> Property BelongsTo Category

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id','id');
}
```

Now if you want to access it from controller then you may use with();

```
$property = Property::with('categories.project')->first();
```

Here you'll get `$property->categories->project->name`

**Note:** If you want to get property from the project then you can use `hasOneThrough` but inverse relation you can't make it.